# How to lock database rows with pgpool master - slave?

Tags: postgresql, redis, pgpool

I have a Pgpool system with several nodes working on master-slave mode. I also have some resources that have a high level concurrency and there are too many rollbacks.

I was thinking in two solutions:

- Use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` queries to block rows and send it only to the master node (with pgpool select for update are not available). Actually, I would have to send the whole transaction at master.
- Use redis distribute locks to block each row, and use normal `SELECT` without locks.

Which solution is better? Any others solutions to solve that problem?

Comment: Do [advisory locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS) work with pgPool?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I would say no, but not sure. Pgpool seems like an nginx, so only data is synchronized.

Comment: @Serginho what did you end up doing?